# Difference between updatePagePadding and updatedlayout

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

With the new jQuery Mobile 1.1.1 came a new option `updatePagePadding`. What's the diference between this new property and the existing property `updatelayout` (which can trigger the toolbars to re-position when dynamic content is injected)? Is `updatePagePadding` only applied to fixed toolbars?